# Increasing download speed for torrents?

Tags: speed, file-sharing, bittorrent, p2p

Can you please list out **any** torrent client configuration to get max out of available net speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Vuze**

- [Vuze (Azureus) speed guide](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/optimizing-vuze-speed.htm)
- [Vuze Beginner’s Guide](http://www.zeropaid.com/news/9811/vuze_40__a_beginners_guide_to_bittorrent/)

**BitComet**

- [BitComet Speed Guides](http://www.p2pforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=6431)

**More tips from torrentfreak**

- [Speed up your torrents](http://torrentfreak.com/speed-up-your-torrents/) (pelms)
- [Speed up your torrents II](http://torrentfreak.com/speed-up-your-torrents-ii/)
- [Speed up Bitcomet and uTorrent](http://torrentfreak.com/speed-up-bitcomet-and-%C2%B5torrent/)
- [Optimize Your BitTorrent Download Speed](http://torrentfreak.com/optimize-your-BitTorrent-download-speed/)
- [uTorrent Developer Shares BitTorrent Speed Tips](http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-developer-shares-bittorrent-speed-tips-080805/)

Comment: I have to -1 for BitComet. It is an abusive torrent client which is intentionally unfair to its peers.

Answer (score 4):

The [**uTorrent** speed guide](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=15992) and [connection setup guide](http://www.utorrent.com/documentation/connection-setup/) (some [quick notes](http://hubpages.com/hub/uTorrent-optimum-speed-How-to-get-optimum-speed-on-uTorrent)).

- [BitTorrent connection guide](http://www.bittorrent.com/btusers/guides/bittorrent-connection-guide).
- [BitTorrent guide](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/bittorrent/qt/bittorrentports.htm) at About.com

Answer (score 1):

Try these tips from [TorrentFreak](http://torrentfreak.com/speed-up-your-torrents/).

The factor that made the most difference for me was to limit the upload speed.
For instance, for my 2Mb/s connection  I limited the upload speed to about 1/15 of the maximum download rate, i.e. an upload rate of 136kb/s (17kB/s) - TorrentFreak recommends setting the upload speed to about 80% of the **measured** maximum upload rate. If the upload is set too high it will slow down the downloads since they need to use some upload capacity for requests.

P.S. Of course I also set the torrent client to switch to unlimited upload speeds once downloads are complete so I can seed the torrents more quickly.

Comment: +1 for removing your upload speed throttling. That is, don't limit your upload speed and the download speed will be much faster.

Comment: @Homer6. Actually, it's the reverse.. throttling back you upload speed  in your torrent client will increase your download rate (up to a point). Setting the upload speed to 'unlimited' can choke the downloads as the the downloads require upstream bandwidth of their own.

Comment: I've observed otherwise. When I don't limit my upload speed, but download speed maxes out my connection.

Answer (score 1):

For underground content (the stuff you shouldn't be downloading) try to find a private tracker, they'll give amazing speeds as everyone there is desperate to upload.

For legitimate traffic - you shouldn't have a problem, unless someone creates a new torrent for an existing file.

Don't hammer your outbound bandwidth - set it at 50-75% of your capacity, a clogged out-bound channel will nerf your inbound traffic. Also, don't run too many torrents at once.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main things that may help.

1. If you are connecting from behind a router make sure the port you are connecting for the torrents has been forwarded (check here for guides: [PortForward.com](http://portforward.com/))
2. While looking for downloads try to not get something redicualisly large.
   Ie. if i want to get a movie for my iPhone i wouldn't get the 8Gig copy over the 1Gig copy.
3. Look for the amount of seeders to leechers. Seeders are people who have already downloaded the file and are sharing it for others to download. Leechers are the people who are downloading the file as well.
   So i wouldn't even bother getting a file that has 1 seeder and 20 leechers.

Answer (score 0):

my way to get Max Speed

- Look for a torrent with at least 10 seeds
- limit uploading to 5kb/s until download finish
- seed the torrent until it get a 0.8 or 0.7 ratio

That's all and it's always working at full speed for me

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that some ISPs are putting a cap on the maximum speed you can get via torrent clients. These ISPs are detecting the protocol torrent clients are using, and slow it down on purpose.

You should consider using a client using the newer uTP protocol (such as uTorrent's beta) for best performance.

You can read more about it [here](http://technomosh.blogspot.com/search?q=utp).