# How do I optimize bit torrent on my fast university connection?

Tags: bittorrent

I've read a lot of guides for optimizing bit torrent, but they're usually aimed at DSL or cable modem type bandwidth.  I get about 50mbps download and upload right now. Is the following guidelines recommended for my connection?? Some of the choices seem a bit extreme...

1) Maximum upload speed... I just picked a number: 1200kBs
I dunno how to convert my 40Mbps speed test result to kBps...

2) max connected peers per torrent: 1560 users
guide says upload speed * 1.3

3) Global maximum number of connections: 3000 users
no clue what to set here

4) Maximum upload slots: 201
guide says 1 + (upload speed / 6)

Please give me some tips. I have no idea if these settings are reasonable.. what is the maximum connections an i7 server can handle??

Comment: You might post what OS and what BT client you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing download speed for torrents?](http://superuser.com/questions/24225/increasing-download-speed-for-torrents)

Comment: the server is a windows 2008 r2 machine.. I just have the standard bittorrent client installed.

@Sathya I didnt think it was a duplicate because as I said above, those questions and answers revolve around relatively small bandwidth. My question is specifically concerning bigger bandwidth optimization. I can make a new question that is more explicit if you want..

Answer (score 1):

Here's Wolfram Alpha's answer to the conversion question: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What+is+40+Mbps+in+KB%2Fs%3F.

So maximum upload speed = 5000 kB/s.

Using your guide, that gives:
Max connected peers per torrent: 6500
Global maximum number of connections: not sure (sorry!)
Maximum upload slots: 833

Keep in mind that you might want to fly under the radar a bit and set those numbers lower.  Your university may throttle P2P traffic as a matter of policy but they may not throttle you if your bandwidth use is moderate.  Universities are under a lot of pressure from big media to pay attention to this kind of traffic.  I worked for a university where they would look at the top talkers and if they were sharing copyrighted materials, they would have campus security shut them down.

Comment: thanks for doin the math.. Is it ok for a server to handle 6500 connections per torrent?  I don't know if that is a lot or not and I cant really access the performance monitor.

hhehe nah, this university doesnt care. trust me. possibly someone would complain after summer school ends.

Comment: As for whether it's okay for a server to handle 6500 connections per torrent: it depends on the operating system.  6500 does seem like a big number, though.  I use uTorrent with a cable connection and max connections is set to 230, with a max of 80 per torrent.  But my requirements are apparently quite different from yours.  You could just crank up the numbers and see what happens, but at some point BT will stop working efficiently.  Try the numbers above and if they meet your expectations, great!  Otherwise you'll need to experiment.  Sorry I can't be more helpful!