# Can my computer/router handle 5000 bittorrent connections?

Tags: bittorrent, bandwidth

I have a 40Mbit/sec connection. 40Mbit/sec upload and download both. All the bit torrent calculators recommend a value of some seemingly insane number of connections...

What are some reasonable bittorrent settings for this type of connection connected to your average core i7 server running windows 2008 r2 connected to a linksys router?

Thanks

Comment: 40MBit! You cannot achieve 40MB (i.e. Megabytes/Mebibytes) on a 100Mbit ethernet link as it requires 320Mbit of uplink. (More really due to protocol/encoding overhead).

Comment: Similar post by this user here  http://superuser.com/questions/170507/how-do-i-optimize-bit-torrent-on-my-fast-university-connection

Comment: hhehe sorry, I dont really know what I'm typin when it comes to bandwidth and transfer rates.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the router. There is no way an "average linksys" is going to handle anywhere near the number of connections you are trying to run through it. That's the bottleneck.

Grab [one of these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I7F1YK), teach yourself the router configuration, and then maybe you'll be able to do it.

Comment: any idea what the maximum number of connections a linksys could handle?  I have 2 ports going into my room... so I can hook directly into the other connection bypassing the linksys. then I should be hooked up to some good quality equipment.

Comment: @djmc: No, you won't. You'll be hooked up to a nice expensive Cisco router that **also happens to be handling connections for 500 other customers**. Realize you're not the only person using this provider.

Comment: @djmc: The routers may still limit you. I would try to hook into the most directly line possible and cap it at about 2.5k connections, 200 per torrent or so. Limit upload (if you really have 40Mbit) to about 2MB / sec and unlimit the download.

Comment: awesome. thanks for the advice, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Who's your internet provider?!

Anyways, I'd recommend looking at the average speed you're downloading from a peer (uploading to you); let's say it's 1MB/s... then give it ~40-50 connections. IF it's 100KB/s, then try 400-500...

Comment: That's a pretty standard rate for a commercial (non-residential) fiber connection.  Where I'm at this kind of connection will run you about $1600 month.

Comment: ya I have no idea what the bill is... heh but I'm sure it's pricey.

I guess I'll just have to do some trial and error testing. I'll bump it up to 400-500 and see what haps.

thanks guys.

Comment: Comcast in a few states (including mine, Minnesota) offers 50mbit